# how to extract jwt in envoy

Tags: jwt, envoyproxy

**how to **extract** jwt in **envoy** on put the extracted values to header**

I need to add some extra properties below the **http_filters** but I have no idea about it and I've researched about **jwtProvider** and **jwtHeader** that both come in envoy docs

this is my **envoy.yaml** file
what's wrong with this configuration:

```
admin: 
  access_log_path: "/dev/null"
  address: 
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 8001
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: main
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 1337
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  host_rewrite_literal: 0.0.0.0
                  cluster: web_service
          http_filters:
          - name: config.filter.http.jwt_authn.v2alpha.JwtHeader
            from_params:
            - jwt_token
          - name: envoy.filters.http.lua
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
              inline_code: |
                function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                  local meta = request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata()
                  for key, value in pairs(meta) do
                    request_handle:logInfo("extract dynamicMetadata key: "..key)
                    request_handle:logInfo("extract dynamicMetadata value: "..value.jwt_payload.usr)
                  end
                end
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: web_service
    connect_timeout: 5s
    type: STRICT_DNS  # static
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: web_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 3000`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you want that :

1. envoy extracts and verifies the JWT from `Authorization` header (`Authorization: Bearer ...`)
2. if the JWT is verified, envoy forwards the request to your cluster
3. in that forwarding request, envoy adds one or more headers corresponding to the decoded JWT payload items

You can do so by changing the `http_filters` part of your configuration. I am using envoy v1.21.0. For convenience, I am using here a [local JWKS](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/jwt_authn/v3/config.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-extensions-filters-http-jwt-authn-v3-jwtprovider-local-jwks) config (`HS256` algorithm, with secret `helloworld` = `aGVsbG93b3JsZA==` in `base64`). But note that you can also [define a remote JWKS config](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/jwt_authn/v3/config.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-extensions-filters-http-jwt-authn-v3-jwtprovider-remote-jwks).

```yaml
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
            typed_config:
              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication"
              providers:
                jwt_auth:
                  local_jwks:
                    inline_string: '{"keys":[{"typ": "JWT", "kty":"oct","alg":"HS256","kid":"df","k":"aGVsbG93b3JsZA=="}]}'
                  from_headers:
                  - name: Authorization
                    value_prefix: "Bearer "
                  payload_in_metadata: jwt_payload
              rules:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                requires:
                  provider_name: jwt_auth
          - name: envoy.filters.http.lua
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
              inline_code: |
                function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                  local meta = request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata()
                  for key, value in pairs(meta) do
                    request_handle:headers():add("jwt-extracted-user", value.jwt_payload.usr)
                  end
                end
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
```

#### First filter (`envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn`)

The first filter (`envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn`) is configured to :

- use some local JWKS configuration : see `local_jwks.inline_string`
- get the JWT from `Authorization` header (after the `Bearer`  part) : see `from_headers` attribute
- write verified JWT payloads to `StreamInfo` `DynamicMetadata` with value `jwt_payload` : see [`payload_in_metadata`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/jwt_authn/v3/config.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-extensions-filters-http-jwt-authn-v3-jwtprovider-payload-in-metadata)
- define some rules to link a match with the provider defined above (`jwt_auth`) : see `rules`

#### Second filter (`envoy.filters.http.lua`)

Once this first filter is configured, you can now process `StreamInfo` `DynamicMetadata` to add new headers. This is done by the second filter (`envoy.filters.http.lua`). The inline code :

```lua
function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
  local meta = request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata()
  for key, value in pairs(meta) do
    request_handle:headers():add("jwt-extracted-user", value.jwt_payload.usr)
  end
end
```

- iterates on `StreamInfo` `DynamicMetadata`
- extract the `usr` field from the JWT payload (named `jwt_payload`, as configured in the first filter's `payload_in_metadata` attribute)
- add that info (`value.jwt_payload.usr`) in a new header called `jwt-extracted-user`

#### Test

With my answer's `http_filters` replacing yours in your configuration, you can spin up an envoy that does what you want and test it with a [valid JWT](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c3IiOiJKb2huIERvZSJ9.-9p297JIIXkHomuuvAFD7pghEtDhdKKAe8V0SqeDqU4) containing the following payload :

```json
{
  "usr": "John Doe"
}
```

Just run :

```sh
curl \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c3IiOiJKb2huIERvZSJ9.-9p297JIIXkHomuuvAFD7pghEtDhdKKAe8V0SqeDqU4' \
  http://localhost:1337
```

The JWT is validated by envoy, forwarded to your `web_service` with a new header called `jwt-extracted-user`. To demonstrate that, I have used a simple Flask Python application for your `web_service`, just printing the headers :

```py
import sys
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    print(request.headers, file=sys.stderr)
    return "Hello, world!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

In the logs of the Python app, you should see something like :

```
Host: localhost:1337
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Request-Id: 3a45f721-ccdd-4225-91ab-8ff4307c97de
Jwt-Extracted-User: John Doe
X-Envoy-Expected-Rq-Timeout-Ms: 15000
```

Note the presence of `Jwt-Extracted-User`, containing the `usr` field of the JWT payload.

#### Credits

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/9716#issuecomment-577261856

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer from [norbjd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101808/6563567), from envoyproxy version v1.25.0 there is a way to Copy validated [JWT claims to HTTP request](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/23444) headers. Here is [the doc](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/jwt_authn_filter.html?highlight=jwt#copy-validated-jwt-claims-to-http-request-headers-example).

Below is the snippet from the config that I'm using. This config will copy the `sub` claim from the JWT token to `x-jwt-claim-sub` request header.

```
  - name: envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn
    typed_config:
      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.jwt_authn.v3.JwtAuthentication
      providers:
        my-idp:
          forward: true
          issuer: https://auth.my-idp.com/oauth2/rfthdw56433d
          claim_to_headers:
          - header_name: x-jwt-claim-sub
            claim_name: sub
          audiences:
            - api://myapi
          ...
          ...
```